# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController::route does not exist

Tags: laravel, routes

am trying to store an ticket using store function in tickets Controller

```
// Create Ticket


 $ticket=new Ticket;
  $ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
  $ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
  $ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
  $ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
  $ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
  $ticket->event_id = $this->route('id');
  $ticket->save();

  return redirect('/');
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::post('ticketstore', 'TicketsController@store')->name('ticketstore');
```

The form action

```
<form action="{{route('ticketstore')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
```

am getting that error

Comment: `$this->route('id');` doesn't work, cause `Controller` classes (referenced by `$this`) don't have a function `route()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So change this

```
 $this->route('id');
```

with

```
 $request->route('id');
```

calling it on this works within FormRequest.

--- EDIT

Now you are trying to get the ID of the event through the request but you are not passing it:

```
Route::post('ticketstore/{event}', 'TicketsController@store')->name('ticketstore');
```

Then in your route you should pass the event:

```
{{route('ticketstore', $event)}}
```

and you can get it using `$request->route('event')` or in the method signature like so:

```
public function store(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    ...
    $ticket->event_id = $event->id;
    ...
}
```

Or if you have a dropdown with events in your view just get the event ID from the request `$request->event_id;`

Comment: am getting this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'event_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tickets` its kind of not saving

Comment: @mimikiduchu I edited my answer.. you should use one of those options. Because you don't have the `event_id` in the route, but you are trying to use it.

Comment: so the event id am getting it from the url

Comment: oh yaa i see my error now am getting another error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Event' not found i've included the model in the controller

Comment: you should have an import above.. `use App\Event;`

Comment: oh i had not included it in the other controller thanks for the help